# A state mutation was detected between dispatches, Redux toolkit and selectors/reselect

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-thunk, redux-toolkit, reselect

I'm having some trouble regarding `createSelector` and async thunk.

Basically I'm trying to retrieve a list of links, and sort them depending on how many clicks they have, from highest to lowest.

Here is my simplified code.

MainPage.tsx

```
export const MainPage = (): JSX.Element => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const allLinks = useSelector(selectLinks);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getLinks());
  }, [dispatch]);

  return (
    <div>
      {allLinks.map((link) => ()} //unrelated logic
    </div>
  );
};
```

links.actions.ts

```
export const getLinks = createAsyncThunk(
  "getLinks",
  async () => {
    const links = await axios.get"/links")
    return links;
  },
);
```

links.slice.ts

```
const linksSlice = createSlice({
  name: "data",
  initialState,
  reducers: {},
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder
    .addCase(
      getLinks.fulfilled,
      (state, action) => {
        state.links = action.payload;
      },
    );
  },
});
```

links.selectors.ts

```
const selectLinksState = (state: RootState) => state.links;

export const selectLinks = createSelector(selectLinksState, (state) =>
  state.links.sort((a, b) => b.clickCount - a.clickCount),
);
```

So this compiles fine, but when I open it in the web browser, I get the following error `Error: Invariant failed: A state mutation was detected between dispatches`

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? I'm pretty sure it's something to do with the selectors because if I sort the links directly after fetching them in the action, it works fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So even though Redux toolkit is mutable, I tinkered around with the reselect function and changed it to so:

```
export const selectLinks = createSelector(selectLinksState, (state) => {
  const sortedArray = [...state.links].sort(
    (a, b) => b.clickCount - a.clickCount,
  );
  return sortedArray;
});
```

My logic was to create a new array, so that it wouldn't cause any mutation problems. It works fine now!

Answer (score 4):

Sort uses an in-place sorting algorithm, it doesn't return a new array, so you are mutating the state via the selector logic.

[Array.prototype.sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

> The `sort()` method sorts the elements of an array in place and returns
> the sorted array. The default sort order is ascending, built upon
> converting the elements into strings, then comparing their sequences
> of UTF-16 code units values.

You can create a copy of the `links` array by using `.slice` in-line and then sort the *new* array reference:

```
export const selectLinks = createSelector(
  [selectLinksState],
  (state) => state.links.slice().sort((a, b) => b.clickCount - a.clickCount),
);
```

Comment: Thanks, I managed to figure out the cause a few minutes ago. Thanks for reaffirming !

Comment: @ffx292 Yeah, I was most of the way through typing up an answer and saw another answer pop up and wanted to ensure mine was sufficiently different before submitting. Didn't notice it was a self-answer. Cheers.